# Looping SQL Server for one or more criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop, foreach, sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and I am trying to run an query with a parameter from the client app that will return dynamic values. This should then be run independently for each parameter...

i.e.

```
PARAM VALUE contains 1,2,3,4,5

Loop for each <PARAM VALUE>
   Select * from Table where ID = <PARAM VALUE>
Next
```

How would I loop for each comma delimited value and run the query independently?

The end all goal is I am going to insert each pass into a new temp table as results.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Any reason it can't just be single insert to temp table? `SELECT * INTO #T FROM Table WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 5`

Comment: Yes, I do some complex math calculation in the query that would break if I selected multiple IDs at the same time. So I am going to run it for each pass against ID so the numbers line up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a table variable to loop through the values:

```
DECLARE @Values TABLE (Index INT)
INSERT @Values VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
DECLARE @Index INT
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Values) BEGIN
    SET @Index = (SELECT TOP 1 Index FROM @Values)
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = @Index
    DELETE @Values WHERE Index = @Index
END
```

If the list of values is a sequence, then a more typical loop can be used:

```
DECLARE @Index INT = 1
WHILE @Index <= 5 BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = @Index
    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END
```

Comment: Awesome, This is what I was looking at doing. Thank you for the confirmation.